# How to modularise function in Chakram to get values

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, web-api-testing, chakram

I have an API that returns data in this format -

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 121,
        "id_type": "some string",
        "id_value": "test",

        "attribute1": {
            "attr_id": 140,
            "attribute_client_id": null,

        },
        "attribute2": {
            "attr2_id": 143,
            "attribute2_client_id": null,

        },
        "status": "some string",
        "person_name": "James Allen",
        "friends": [
            {
                "friend_id": 1,
                "data_id": null,
            },
            {
                "friend_id": 2,
                "data_id":null

            }
        ],
        "text_description": "Some string",
        "text_format": [
            "something",
            "else"
        ],
        "job_description": "new string",
        "is_member": false,
        "is_external": false
    },
     .... 
]
}
```

I want to have a function that calculates if of array with `is_member` is true.

I can do this in the code itself using the `filter` function with something like this - I am using `Chakram` library to hit the API end points.

```
describe('Check if is member is true',()=>{
     it('get data',()=>{
        let length_of_arr
    return response.then((resp)=>{
        let length_of_arr = resp.body.data;
        length_of_arr.length= Object.keys(length_of_arr).length;
        console.log(length_of_arr);
        let new_arr = Array.from(length_of_arr);
        let r = new_arr.filter(({is_member})=>is_member === true);
        console.log(r.length);
        expect(r.length).to.be.greater.than(0);
       })  ; 
   });
```

This works perfectly fine and I am able to get the correct results. However, I need to use this same test for the same API at other places too. So I wanted to have a function which can do it.

In the root directory, I created a file `custom_functions.js`, which has code like

```
module.exports = {
            get_member_details(resp,data,attr){
           let length_of_arr;
        let length_of_arr = resp.body.data;
        length_of_arr.length= Object.keys(length_of_arr).length;
        console.log(length_of_arr);
        let new_arr = Array.from(length_of_arr);
        let r = new_arr.filter(({attr})=>attr === true);
        console.log(r.length);

}
}
```

However, this is not correct and it gives error that `data` is not defined. How can I achieve this kind of modularisation when using Javascript. I would also welcome if there are suggestions to improve how to approach this problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you want to define a function that you can call it in many tests:

```
//custom_functions.js

function has_member(data){
  return data.filter(res => res.is_member).length > 0;
}

module.exports = {
 has_member,
}
```

// in your test you can call this function like this :

```
const { has_member } require ('./custom_functions');

describe('Check if is member is true',()=>{
    it('get data',() => {
       return response.then((resp)=>{
        const data = resp.body.data;
        const has_member = has_member(data);
        expect(has_member).to.be.true;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Instead of `data.data.filter` it should be `data.filter`, and the example works. Thanks. Please edit the answer and I will accept it.